# Issue invoking web service within websphere 6.1 environment

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere-6.1

I'm trying to invoke a SOAP web service from within WebSphere 6.1.  I can run the code fine using Apache Tomcat 6.0.36 runtime.  However, with WebSphere 6.1, I get the following error:

```
Jan 5, 2015 7:19:23 PM com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager INFO:ssl.disable.url.hostname.verification.CWPKI0027I 
Jan 5, 2015 7:19:24 PM com.ibm.ws.channel.framework.impl.WSChannelFrameworkImpl AUDIT: chain.started 
Jan 5, 2015 7:19:25 PM com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper invoke WARNING:
WSWS3734W: Warning: Exception caught from invocation to com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTPSender:
WebServicesFault  faultCode: 
HTTP  faultString: ( 401 ) Unauthorized faultActor: http://server.customer.com:80
faultDetail:    null:
WSWS3192E: Error: return code:  ( 401 ) Unauthorized
```

Here's the code I'm running, which works fine in Apache Tomcat:

```
public class Test {

    public void submitOrder()
    {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "http://server.customer.com/serviceEndpoint";

            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        MimeHeaders hd = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        String username = "xxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxx";
        byte [] auth = (username+":"+password).getBytes();
        String authorization = new String ( Base64.encodeBase64(auth) );

        System.out.println ( "authorization = " + authorization );

        hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);

        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement ordersElem = soapBody.addChildElement("Orders");

//      Need to add two attributes to this node!
        SOAPElement orderElem = ordersElem.addChildElement("Order");

        Name codeAttributeName = envelope.createName("code");
        orderElem.addAttribute(codeAttributeName, "00001");

        Name timeAttributeName = envelope.createName("time");
        orderElem.addAttribute(timeAttributeName, "2015-01-04 12:00:00 PM");

        SOAPElement salesOrderConfElem = orderElem.addChildElement("SalesOrderConfirmationCode");
        salesOrderConfElem.addTextNode("16041");

        SOAPElement statusElem = orderElem.addChildElement("Status");
        Name statusCodeAttributeName = envelope.createName("code");
        statusElem.addAttribute(statusCodeAttributeName, "COMPLETE");

        SOAPElement entriesElem = orderElem.addChildElement("Entries");
        SOAPElement entryElem = entriesElem.addChildElement("Entry");

        SOAPElement entryNumElem = entryElem.addChildElement("EntryNumber");
        entryNumElem.addTextNode("1");

        SOAPElement productElem = entryElem.addChildElement("ProductCode");
        productElem.addTextNode("738053571");

        SOAPElement qtyElem = entryElem.addChildElement("Quantity");
        qtyElem.addTextNode("1");

        SOAPElement shippedElem = entryElem.addChildElement("Shipped");
        shippedElem.addTextNode("1");

        SOAPElement backOrderElem = entryElem.addChildElement("Backordered");
        backOrderElem.addTextNode("1");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to print the SOAP Response
     */
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.submitOrder();

    }
}
```

CORRECTION: the SOAP envelopes being created by Tomcat and WebSphere are not the same.  Tomcat, using Java 1.6, creates the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Orders>
```

while WebSphere, using IBM's version of 1.5, creates the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Orders>
```

How would I get WebSphere to create the same SOAP envelop as Tomcat?

Comment: `HTTP  faultString: ( 401 ) Unauthorized` suggests that you might be using incorrect credentials. Maybe you didnt correctly map security roles to users in your application.

Comment: The code is included within a J2EE application that has its own security.  Are you saying that I need to enable Java 2 security, define users and roles just for WebSphere to be able to invoke an external SOAP web service?

Comment: No, I thouhgt that service is also on your WAS. But still, it looks like that external service is returning Unauthorized. So either you are passing different credentials, or service is expecting something else what maybe is set differently when sending from WAS. Try to log both outgoing messages and compare.

Comment: Thank you for telling me to compare the messages!  My original assumption was wrong.  The SOAP envelopes being created by Tomcat and WebSphere are different.  How would I get WebSphere, running IBM's flavor of 1.5, to create the same SOAP envelope as Tomcat, running Oracle's 1.6?

Comment: This difference is just a namespace prefix, so should be compatible. You could try to test it using SOAPUI. I was rather thinking of the http headers that goes with the message.

Comment: I can invoke the service no problem with soapUI.  It seems the issue is with the WebSphere 6.1 runtime enviornment.

Comment: Michael, can you replace the content in the soapUI with the message produced by WAS and check if it works then? So whether it is the problem with format of the message or something else. Maybe a different host? Is soapui and tomcat on same machine, while WAS on different?

Comment: soapUI was able to ping the web service successfully, for both the soapenv:Envelope and SOAP-ENV:Envelope prefixes.  I can also successfully ping the web service using soapUI on the machine running WebSphere and the machine running Tomcat.

Comment: So now I'm really confused. As I understand, you tired both messages generated by Tomcat and WAS and they both work correctly via SoapUI. So how you are gathering username that is send? Is it fixed and same for both servers? Maybe use burp proxy or wireshark to compare whole communication with http Authentication header. Sorry no more good ideas.

Comment: I opened a ticket with IBM Support.  They identified the problem as resulting from not having the Web Service Feature Pack installed.  That feature pack is installed with WAS 7.0 by default.  So, I need to install the feature pack, update it to the latest FP and then recreate all of my existing profiles.  Either that or I learn to use something else like Apache Axis instead.

Comment: Thanks for update. In general you should consider moving to higher version as 6.1 is already out of support for quite a time... Maybe it will be easier than this whole FP stuff.

Comment: The app that is running on WAS 6.1 won't run under WAS 7.0.  I can't install a later version of the app because the current version of the app has been heavily modified (by me).  So, I'm stuck with WAS 6.1 for the near term.